# How can I use Menelaus' theorem here (Simson line)?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given 4 points on a circle A, B, C, and P.  Draw the orthogonal projections of P onto triangle ABC and call them $P_1, P_2,P_3$. Show that $P_1, P_2,P_3$ are collinear.

After drawing this out, I notice that the configuration looks exactly like the one for Menelaus' theorem.  Unfortunately I am inexperienced with using it.  Is this the right way to go about the problem or is there an easier different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Simson theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimsonLine.html)  can be proved by angle chasing only.

$\hspace2in$[image: Simson line]

Since $BP_1 P P_2$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $$\widehat{BP_2 P_1}=\widehat{BPP_1}=\widehat{ABP}-\frac{\pi}{2},$$

and since $CPP_2P_3$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $$\widehat{CP_2 P_3}=\widehat{CPP_3}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\widehat{PCA},$$
so $\widehat{BP_2 P_1}=\widehat{CP_2 P_3}$ proves that $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are collinear.

Comment: And the downvote is for... what?

Comment: It can be solved by methods other than angle chasing

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith: I do not want to sound rude, but "it can be solved through some other method" does not look as a sound reason for a downvote.

Comment: It's okay - I don't think you are being rude.

The question asked, "How can I use Menelaus Theorem here?" Your reply didn't answer the question.

Comment: All right, then. One may apply basic trigonometry and Menelaus' theorem, or just angle chasing.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known fact that these three points are collinear. They lie on so-called Simson line of point $P$ with respect to triangle $ABC$.

I think you can use a Menelaus' theorem here. Assume that $P_1 \in BC$, $P_2 \in CA$ and $P_3 \in AB$. Note that $\frac{BP_1}{P_1C} = \frac{\cot \angle PBC}{\cot \angle PCB}$ and so on. After multiplying this equality with two analogous ones, the right side will cancel out and you'll get $\frac{BP_1}{P_1C} \cdot \frac{CP_2}{P_2A} \cdot \frac{AP_3}{P_3B} = 1$.

Another way to prove it is noting that the following quadruples of points are concyclic: $(P,P_2,P_3,A)$, $(P, P_3, P_1, B)$ and $(P,P_1,P_2,C)$. Then it is just easy angle calculation.